# initializer_list constructor with default argument

Tags: c++, constructor, initializer-list, default-arguments

I define a initializer list ctor (sequence ctor) in a class and give it a default argument like this:

```
class Box 
{
public:
    Box(std::initializer_list<XMFLOAT3> vertices = {XMFLOAT3(), XMFLOAT3(), XMFLOAT3(), XMFLOAT3(), XMFLOAT3(), XMFLOAT3(), XMFLOAT3(), XMFLOAT3()});
    ~Box();
    void SetVertices(std::initializer_list<XMFLOAT3> vertices);
    XMFLOAT3 (&GetVertices())[8];
    Mesh &GetMesh() { return mMesh; }
private:
    XMFLOAT3 mVertices[8];
    Mesh mMesh;
};
```

but when I put an object of type Box inside another class the compiler complains that there's no default ctor available. Why?

**EDIT**
if I call the default ctor into the containing class ctor's initialization list:

```
Bone::Bone(std::string const &name) : mName(name), mCollisionBox{}
{
}
```

(I understand that when an initializer_list ctor is present the brace notation calls the default ctor first, not the initializer_list ctor with an empty list)
it calls the default ctor.

The default ctor is also called if I explicitly call it:

```
Bone::Bone(std::string const &name) : mName(name), mCollisionBox()
{
}
```

I'm using VisualC++ with Visual studio 2017
that's really strange..

**EDIT 2**

in this example it works, but as I pointed out on the commented line it doesn't in VS 2017

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1de3b215c6c4634

Comment: As [mcve] this seems to work fine: [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea7ce6b813c6e5af). (I know that VS2013 and initializer lists... - bad story.)

Comment: @Scheff what if you remove the explicit call to Box's default ctor in Other's ctor's initializer list?

Comment: I tried before (and now again). It compiles as well. But it's `g++ 8.1.0` with `-std=c++14`. [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/735f54ed0820784a)

Comment: I also can't reproduce... http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ffe46d5001b04650 ... What is the exact error message and where does it occure? Post a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This just becoming a guessing game right now...

Comment: I tried again on godbolt (where I can choose MSVC): [**Live Demo on godbolt**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WixFtg).

Comment: Could you add the exact error that you're getting and a MCVE, as requested by Scheff? I'm unable to reproduce your error either, with VS2017.

Comment: @divinas  posted

Comment: The MSVC version on godbolt might be the most up-to-date. (On the bottom, it is stated as `Version 19.10.25017`.) You might compare it with the one which is used on your side. May be, a simple update would help. (As I already stated, in the very older version with VS2013, it doesn't work. MS seemed to have had a certain effort to fix their initializer lists issues, and I don't know in which version these fixes became available.)

Comment: I'm still unable to reproduce you with your example. I'm compiling with VS 15.7.3, with /std:C++14 or /std::C++17 and /Wall.

This is my complete command line for completeness:
/permissive- /GS /analyze- /Wall /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm- /Od /sdl /Fd"Debug\vc141.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /MDd /std:c++17 /FC /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\Testy.pch" /diagnostics:classic

Comment: [**MSDN**](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/cpp/initializers?view=vs-2017) stated: _In Visual Studio 2015 and earlier, an aggregate is not allowed to have brace-or-equal initializers for non-static members. This restriction was removed in the C++14 standard and implemented in Visual Studio 2017._ but they don't mention the actual version... Regarding `/std:C++14` (mentioned by @divinas): What do you use?

Comment: @Scheff I'm using vs 2017

Comment: I just found this: [MSDN: /std (Specify Language Standard Version)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=vs-2017). It's not possible to specify something less than `c++14`.

Comment: I just tried to find out how you can ask VC for its version. In `g++` (and probably `clang` as well), it's simply `g++ --version`. In VS2013, I opened the console and typed `cl`. Among others, it told me the version: `Microsoft (R) C/C++-Optimierungscompiler Version 18.00.40629 für x64`. This should be somehow possible also in/for VS2017.

Answer (score -1):

You are asking the wrong question - because it is perfectly legal what you are asking for. Could be the error is something else or you need to provide a minimal and complete example.

Comment: "when I put an object of type Box inside another class the compiler complains that there's no default ctor available. Why?"

Comment: It works fine - you must provide a working example and minimal one.

Comment: I'm using VIsualC++ in visual studio 2017